# Web API Post with Null body

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, asp.net-web-api, nullable

Hy everybody, I'm trying to understand why if I send a request from my client with a null object my Server doesn't intercept it.

What I'm aiming is to handle a Post call with no object

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Insert2")]
    public IActionResult InsAPers([FromBody(EmptyBodyBehavior =Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.EmptyBodyBehavior.Allow)] object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("il body non può essere nullo");
        }
        else
        {
            return Ok(obj.GetType().ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you send the request?

Comment: Does it even work when the object isn't null?

Comment: perhaps try overloading the action without a "FromBody" parameter